# Подскажите как добавить CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

Здравствуйте. Нашел статью интересную, вот она: [клац](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html). Все отлично, но я не понимаю каким образом добавить checkBox к ней. Подскажите, что лучше: checkBox или какое-либо выделение строки при нажатии? Не могли бы вы дать статейки или примеры как мне это реализовать, а то я совсем новенький в android, не знаю даже с чего начинать поиски

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуй. Тебе нужно рыть в направлении " кастомизация *ListView* ". В свое время пользовался уроками, которые размещены на сайте Александра Климова.

Вот ссылка на урок по твоей теме [> клац <](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/listview.php). Там, как раз, есть пример с CheckBox'ами.